# NameError: name 'self' is not defined_is it version difference issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm teaching myself about python. when I run below example codes in book error occurs even the code is exactly same with book.

I tried to search for solution in google, but no clue for me.

die.py

```
from random import randint

class Die():
    """A class representing a single die."""

    def __init__(sefl, num_sides=6):
        """Assume a six-sided die."""
        self.num_sides = num_sides

    def roll(self):
        """Return a random value between 1 and number of sides."""
        return randint(1, self.num_sides)
```

die_visual.py

```
from die import Die

# Create a D6.
die = Die()

# Make some rolls, and store results in a list.
results = []
for roll_num in range(100):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)

print(results)
```

it has to show me random list of playing die.

Comment: Typo: You have written `sefl` instead of `self` in your `__init__` parameters.

Comment: is `sefl` a mistake or your actual code?

Comment: If that's exactly the same as in the book, your book has a typo.

Comment: Nothing to do with versions. That is a typo in *any* version of Python.

Comment: It's actually a nice demonstration that `self` is a convention for naming the first parameter of a method in Python, not an enforced  feature. You could have used `sefl.num_sides = num_sides` and it would have worked. (Don't, though.)

Comment: __init__ function will take self as its 1st parameter

Comment: Thanks guys. it was typo. when I fixed it to self, it works. I appreciate your comments.